# How do accessor properties work inside in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, storage, accessor

I have noticed that using accessor properties instead of data properties in js then the object is forced to store the value of the property twice:

```
let obj = {
  get propName(){
    return this._propName;
  },
  set propName(value){
   this._propName = value;
  }
}

obj.propName = "some_value";

for(let key in obj){
  if((obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) && (typeof key != 'function')){
    console.log(key + ": " + obj[key])
  }
}
```

The output is:

`propName: some_value`

`_propName: some_value`

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, thats funny, but if you create a class with accessors, propName property will not be in it

Comment: Your code snippet looks like it was cut in the middle, and the latter part of your question is misformatted as code. Can you fix it?

Comment: "*the object is forced to store the value of the property twice*" - no. The point is that an accessor property doesn't store anything, it just makes a value available (that's typically stored elsewhere, or created on the fly).